# Firebase Function always finished with timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

i am using firebase function for creating notifications with cloud messaging.
But i am always getting this Error:

```
Function execution took 60006 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

but the notification works.

This is the code i am using in index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.SendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {  

  var payload = {
      notification: {
         title: "this is a test",
         body: req.rawBody.toString('utf8')
      }
  }

  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload);

});
```

Do i have to implement a response? When, how do i do that?

J3nsis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A HTTPS-triggered Cloud Function ends when it sends a response to its caller. Since your code never sends a response, the code keep running until its configured timeout (which is 1 minute by default).

To properly terminate the function when it's done, send a result back after the FCM call completes:

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send("ok");
}).catch((err) => {
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

I recommend reading this section in the docs:

- [Terminate HTTP Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions)